# Reading data from directory PHP to Jquery chart

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I'm trying to make my php set a variable from a text document in my site directory, then using my JQuery to set a variable using this directory. However this isn't working as its making the graph go blank. Also I'm trying to do the same thing with the textbox where it sets its value from the same file. Neither of these areas working. However I have commented it out but if I use a simple number in the php variable everything works. Now I know that there is in fact a value in the text file as if I echo after setting the variable from the file I get an output of what I wanted. So why isn't the chart isn't getting this output or the textbox.

**FILE EXAMPLE**

http://server1.sulmaxcp.com/value1.txt

**CONSOLE ERROR**

Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token on line 13:

var pValue1 = '1

**PHP**

```
<?php 
$myFile=fopen("CHARTS/value1.txt","r") or exit("Can't open file!");
$pValue1 = fgets($myFile);
fclose($myFile);

//$pValue1 = 5; 
?>
```

```js
window.onload = function() {
  var pValue1 = '<?php echo $pValue1; ?>';
  var bar = new RGraph.Bar({
    id: 'cvs1',
    data: [pValue1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9],
    options: {
      backgroundGridDashed: true,
      labels: ['Mal', 'Barry', 'Gary', 'Neil', 'Kim', 'Pete', 'Lou', 'Fred', 'Jobe'],
      title: 'A dashed background grid',
      strokestyle: 'rgba(0,0,0,0)',
      textAccessible: true
    }
  }).draw();
};
```

```css
#btn_Charts {
  width: 100px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  background: red;
  border: 1px solid red;
  border-radius: 5px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: underline;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<script src="http://server1.sulmaxcp.com/RGraph.common.core.js"></script>
<script src="http://server1.sulmaxcp.com/RGraph.bar.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="cvs1" width="600" height="250">[No canvas support]</canvas>
<form method="post" action="Charts.php" id="Chart1" autocomplete="off">
  <input type="number" id="tb_1" name="tb_1" <?php echo 'value="'.$pValue1. '"';?>>
  <div id="btn_Charts" onclick="javascript:this.parentNode.submit();">
    <p>Update</p>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: have you tried `parseInt` when using the variable `pValue1`? ie `data: [parseInt( pValue1 ), 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]`

Comment: Thanks for helping here, but unfortunately this is still giving the same result?

Comment: and there are no errors in the console that give any pointers as to what is going wrong? Are you sure that the value returned by `fgets( $myfile )` returns a string with no line break charachter or odd blank spaces?

Comment: I've added an edit which shows file example and the console error.

Comment: the error message shows a leading single quote to the actual value. So, either the generation of the textfile or the reading/processing of it has introduced this spurious character. When I tested the generation of a simple text file containg a single digit and then reading with `fopen` and `fgets` it worked fine when parsed through javascript - using `typeof` suggested a number in my test

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As your Javascript requires integers for the Graph generation then I suggest changing the following:

```
var pValue1 = '<?php echo $pValue1; ?>';
```

to

```
var pValue1 = <?php echo $pValue1; ?>;
```

Comment: This has solved the issue with the chart, thank you for that. Any clue why the textbox value isn't working as well?

Comment: The console is saying The specified value "1\n" is not a valid number. The value must match to the following regular expression: -? Any ideas

Comment: Never mind I cracked it... added `$pValue1 = trim(preg_replace('/\s+/', ' ', $pValue1));` in the php. Thanks again.